# The .sass file has "+column(!main_content_width)" -- what does it mean?

Tags: blueprint-css, sass

Is it actually part of BluePrint?  What do they do?

```
+column(!main_content_width)
+clearfix
```

Where can some intro docs be found for it?  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are part of [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), the stylesheet authoring framework built on top of Sass. See the following:

- http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/blueprint/grid/#mixin-column
- http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/compass/utilities/general/clearfix/

The column mixin is part of the Blueprint module, which is included with Compass.